# Spring Integration JMS DSL

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

We have the below working configuration in XML and are trying to convert to DSL.  Not sure whether they are equivalent and also tried to do with inboundAdapter. However , am unable to figure out how to set concurrency related values there. Can someone please advise if they used either messageDrivenChannelAdapter or  inboundAdapter with these parameters in DSL?

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter 
id="inputChannelAdapter" 
channel="inputChannel" 
destination-name="inboundQueueName"
connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory"
acknowledge="transacted" 
header-mapper="defaultJmsHeaderMapper"
error-channel="errorChannel" 
concurrent-consumers="10"  
max-concurrent-consumers="20"/>



@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory)
                    .configureListenerContainer(c -> {
                        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = c.get();
                        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
                        container.setSessionAcknowledgeModeName("");
                        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(30);
                        container.setConcurrentConsumers(20);
                    })
                    .destination(inboundQueueName).headerMapper(defaultJmsHeaderMapper)
                    .errorChannel("errorChannel"))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("inputChannel"))
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow1() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory)
                    .configureJmsTemplate(t ->
                            t.deliveryPersistent(true).sessionTransacted(true).sessionAcknowledgeModeName(""))
                    .destination(inboundQueueName).headerMapper(defaultJmsHeaderMapper))
                    .channel(MessageChannels.queue("inputChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do with the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = c.get();` is correct way to provide those options.

There is also a variant like use `Jms.container()` factory:

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                Jms.container(this.jmsConnectionFactory, "containerSpecDestination")
                        .concurrentConsumers(20)
                        .maxConcurrentConsumers(30)
                        .get())
```

We will see in Spring Integration `5.0` how we can improve `configureListenerContainer()` to infer generic type for the target container class to let fluent API to deal with the `JmsDefaultListenerContainerSpec` directly.

See the JIRA [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4253) on the matter.